# Como fazer esse efeito ? Animation CSS?

Tags: css, animação

Boa tarde

Há um efeito de um carrinho percorrendo uma estrada no link abaixo:

http://institutosorridents.org.br/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inspecionando o código encontrei o código css abaixo :

```
#rota-do-sorriso > #mapa > #unidade-movel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 97px;
    animation: unidade-movel 10s infinite;
}
```

Percebi que se trata de uma animation um recurso que não vi anteriormente mas eu tentei utilizar o mesmo código desse site mas não consegui.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Fico no aguardo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara o que acontece é que essa propriedade `animation` é um *shorthand* para várias outros atributos, é o mesmo que `background-imagem`, `background-size`, etc. mas com o `animation` é algo como `animation-name`, `animation-direction`, etc... Leia mais aqui. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Usando_anima%C3%A7%C3%B5es_CSS

Sobre essa animação o nome dela é  `unidade-movel` então vc tem que procurar no CSS o `@keyframes unidade-movel` essa é a animação instanciada no `animation`

Repliquei aqui o código para vc entender melhor

```css
 body {
 padding-top:30px;
 }
 #rota-do-sorriso > #mapa > #unidade-movel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 97px;
    animation: unidade-movel 3s infinite;
}

 @keyframes unidade-movel {
  0% {
      top: -64px;
      left: 0%;
  }
  10% {
      top: -64px;
      left: 10%;
  }
  20% {
      top: -64px;
      left: 20%;
  }
  30% {
      top: -64px;
      left: 30%;
  }
  40% {
      top: -26px;
      left: 45%;
  }
  45% {
      top: 28px;
      left: 42%;
  }
  50% {
      top: 75px;
      left: 31%;
  }
  60% {
      top: 97px;
      left: 40%;
  }
  70% {
      top: 97px;
      left: 50%;
  }
  80% {
      top: 97px;
      left: 60%;
  }
  90% {
      top: 97px;
      left: 70%;
  }
  100% {
      top: 97px;
      left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="rota-do-sorriso" class="pt-3 pdd-v">

    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            
            

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mapa" class="d-none d-lg-block">

        <span id="estrada">
            <img src="https://placecage.com/300/100" width="100%" height="auto">
        </span>

        <span id="unidade-movel">
            <img src="https://placecage.com/80/30" alt="Unidade Móvel" width="150rem" height="auto">
        </span>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: só tenho a agradecer, aprendi bastante com sua ajuda e de quebra resolvi meu problema!

Comment: @Grafite sem problemas meu amigo, fico feliz em ter ajudado. Procure na internet por tutoriais de CSS animation vc vai achar muita coisa interessante